# How to create a user and only allow him to add users?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I have my system user roles, in the first image below:

[image]

I want my user level access to be like the second image.

[image]

I am the `administrator` of the site, I want to create a user with a role `MyID Organization Administrator`. This user must be allowed to add users and assign it with the role `MyID Manager`, `MyID Inputter` and `MyID Printer`. `MyID Organization Administrator` must only be allowed to add users and nothing more about administering the website itself. How am I gonna do that?

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/drupal-7-give-permission-to-manage-users-but-not-permissions for the role delegation, the rest is just down to setting up permissions that match what you want them to be able to do. You can be as restrictive (or not) as you like

Comment: Depending on the full use case you might also want to look into the groups and organic groups modules.  Given what you've outline those may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Roledelegation](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module, which allows the admin to delegate certain users the ability to assign other users specific roles. Per the module's page:

> For each role, Role Delegation provides a new assign ROLE role
>   permission to allow the assignment of that role.
>
> The module also adds an assign all roles permission. Enabling this
>   permission for a role is a convenient way to allow the assignment of
>   any other role without having to check all the assign ROLE role
>   permissions on the permissions page.